# Error where laravel connect to google drive folder

Tags: laravel

`Google\Service\Exception { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg", "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.", "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console" } ], "code": 403, "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup." } }`

public function convert(){

```
 $files = Storage::disk('google')->allFiles();

dd($files);  

  return view('frontend.view')->with(compact('files'));

}
```

When i connect from laravel controller to specific google driver. that error appeared.
Which problem i have ? And how could i fix this prolem. Please help me . thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you.  `"message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."`

You have already used up the daily Limit. To make further requests you have to log in, probably with oauth.

**update**

Maybe try this: Go to the Google developer console under apis. Search for your project that your api is key related to. Check if the status for that key happens to be set to OFF. If so, turn it on.

Comment: This is the first time i access today. I don't think limit is only one time a day

Comment: @NghiemHung that would be really little ;-) But that's what the error message says. I updated my answear.

Comment: @NghiemHung and maybe try it with an other browser for test.

Comment: still now i can't fix this problem